# How can I make sure a method I put in my model is accessible from outside?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have a simple model:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :subscribed

  def subscribed
    @subscribed = Subscription.where(task_id, user_id)
    !@subscribed.empty?
  end

end
```

I'd like to make sure I can take a @subscription instance and call @subscription.subscribed - at the moment it can't find the method.

Comment: Do you mean it can't find the function because you don't have a Subscription instance?

Comment: No I seem to have the instance but when if I correctly pull out an instance of Subscription from the database, I can't seem to call the subscribed method on it- but I don't know why not. It's as if it's private, but I never said it should be.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: What does `Subscription.instance_methods.grep(/subscribed/)` tell you?

Comment: >> @subscription.subscribed
NoMethodError: undefined method `subscribed' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x133f46580>
 from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/relation.rb:459:in `method_missing'
 from (irb):4

Comment: I can't say it's looking great that it's an activerecord instance- actually I wasn't expecting that...

Comment: >> Subscription.instance_methods.grep('/subscribed/')
=> []

Comment: Exactly, you're probably calling `subscribed` on a collection of `Subscription`s.

Comment: That's wrong. Try: `Subscription.instance_methods.grep /subscribed/`

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve with your function? The more I look at it the less I understand your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are doing something like:

```
@subscription = Subscription.where(task_id, user_id)
@subscription.subscribed
```

instead of something like this:

```
@subscription = Subscription.where(task_id, user_id).first
@subscription.subscribed
```

It's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is your `where` call. Try this:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :user

  attr_accessor :subscribed

  def subscribed?
    @subscribed ||= !Subscription.where(:task_id => task.id, :user_id => user.id).empty?
  end

end
```

If I'm correctly understanding what you're trying to do I think that should work.

But it still doesn't make a lot of sense to me to have this method on the `Subscription` model. If a subscription exists wouldn't that mean that the user is subscribed automatically. Was this meant to be a class method mabye? I'd think `user.subscribed_to? issue` or `Issue.has_subscriber? user` would be a better place to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you can do:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :subscribed

  def subscribed?
    @subscribed = Subscription.where(task_id, user_id)
    !@subscribed.empty?
  end

end
```

and you can do (a.i):

```
s = Subscription.first
s.subscribed? # true or false
s.subscribed # the object (@subscribed)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your error in the comments, your object called `@subscription` is not pointing to an instance of `Subscription` but instead a relation.

Probably you did something like

```
@subscription = Subscription.where(... some condition ...)
```

which returns a relation, which you can access as an array. So call `.first` to get the first element out of it. Or use `Subscription.find`.

Hope this helps.